# Build errors while using Android library project

Tags: android, library-project

I'm trying to use this library project on github:

https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow

This Android library project provides horizonally swiping.

I will explain my moves how I'm trying to use this library:

1. I downloaded this project from github, and imported "viewflow" project with "Existing Projects into Workspace". (Eclipse gives some errors but I fixed them. It is not the problem.)
2. I created a new android project which name is "test".
3. I added viewflow project to the my test project's build path. (Using Java Build Path->Projects->Add)
4. Here is my main.xml:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.test"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:orientation="vertical" >
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:id="@+id/header_layout"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>         android:orientation="vertical" >
>
>         <org.taptwo.android.widget.TitleFlowIndicator
>             android:id="@+id/viewflowindic"
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
>             app:clipPadding="5dp"
>             app:footerColor="#FFFFC445"
>             app:footerLineHeight="2dp"
>             app:footerTriangleHeight="10dp"
>             app:selectedColor="#FFFFC445"
>             app:selectedSize="12dp"
>             app:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
>             app:textSize="11dp"
>             app:titlePadding="10dp" >
>         </org.taptwo.android.widget.TitleFlowIndicator>
>     </LinearLayout>
>
>     <org.taptwo.android.widget.ViewFlow
>         android:id="@+id/viewflow"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:duplicateParentState="true" >
>     </org.taptwo.android.widget.ViewFlow>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

But Eclipse gives these errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Main.java   /test/src/com/example/test  line 14 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Main.java   /test/src/com/example/test  line 19 Java Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'titlePadding' in package 'com.example.test'  main.xml    /test/res/layout    line 15 Android AAPT Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'textSize' in package 'com.example.test'  main.xml    /test/res/layout    line 15 Android AAPT Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'textColor' in package 'com.example.test' main.xml    /test/res/layout    line 15 Android AAPT Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'selectedSize' in package 'com.example.test'  main.xml    /test/res/layout    line 15 Android AAPT Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'selectedColor' in package 'com.example.test' main.xml    /test/res/layout    line 15 Android AAPT Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'clipPadding' in package 'com.example.test'   main.xml    /test/res/layout    line 15 Android AAPT Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'footerColor' in package 'com.example.test'   main.xml    /test/res/layout    line 15 Android AAPT Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'footerLineHeight' in package 'com.example.test'  main.xml    /test/res/layout    line 15 Android AAPT Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'footerTriangleHeight' in package 'com.example.test'  main.xml    /test/res/layout    line 15 Android AAPT Problem
```

I imported its example project ( https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow/tree/master/viewflow-example ), it just works fine!

The problem could be about namespaces but I couldn't fix this.

Comment: R cannot be resolved to a variable => try clean and build

Comment: Clean library project first, then remove the library project added to your project in build path, now again add the library project to your project and check.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. If I remove org.taptwo.android.widget.TitleFlowIndicator completely, there is no problem. I guess there is a problem with xmlns:app line.

Comment: Clean project, fix project, delete bin folder, restart eclipse.

Comment: just update your android app...Right click on your project>>Properties>>chose android and update it to a high level.

Comment: Not working, I got same errors.

Answer (score 1):

app:selectedSize="12dp" remove this line